# Fatal Error : Adreno-GSL

Tags: android, memory, fatal-error, launcher

sometimes and randomly when i run my app with Eclipse i got this error on launching , the app shuts down unexpectedly with this Error in logcat:

```
   Tag : Adreno-GSL

   Text : <ioctl_kgsl_sharedmem_alloc:1494>:ioctl_kgsl_sharedmem_alloc: FATAL ERROR : (null)
```

i think it's a memory issue but i don't have any idea about that ,does anybody know why this error occurs and how can i solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

**adb shell dumpsys meminfo your.package.name.here**

to check how much memory you are using.  Notably, the GL line in your case.
Strange that it only happens when you run from Eclipse.

Comment: thank you for the answer tomorrow i will check the memory but i think its an issue with my Xperia z device , other devices doesn't throw this error with my app.it throws error on app startup which i just show a splash screen for a moment , then random Error!!

Comment: this command help you alot to detect error, just type this command while running your application every 10-20 seconds and see "Native Heap" and "GL Mtrack" that their memory increase nonlimit or not

Answer (score 3):

I think it is a memory problem. Check your device memory, and your application. It may is using a lot of memory and the android system has to force it to close.